# Cassandra cluster is running but not alble to connect from Spark App

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

**Version:**  Cassandra version **`3.6`** , Spark version **`1.5.2`**, Spark-Cassandra-Connector_2.11 version **`1.5.0-RC1`**

**cassandra.yaml settings:** `listen_address:<node_ip>` , `rpc_address:0.0.0.0` , `broadcast_rpc_address:<node_ip>` , `start_rpc: true` , `start_native_transport: true` , `native_transport_port:9042` , `rpc_port: 9160` , `seeds: 192.168.0.52`

**Scenario:**  I have a cassandra cluster with two nodes and one of them is set as seed.

1. 192.168.0.52 (seed node)
2. 192.168.0.55

I am trying to run a web app on other machine, 192.168.0.60. This machine is currently using spark locally but I also tried it in standalone mode. [ but i am getting same error, so I am currently running the app locally.] I have set the CASSANDRA_DB_IP as `sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.52")`  in Spark app.
The app can't communicate with cassandra db.

**Note:** If I run some file from app ( like .scala file with main() method in object as an individual program ) it runs perfectly and fetches data from the cassandra db normally. But i throws the following exception while try to run the project/app.

```
16/06/21 12:53:13 ERROR DefaultErrorHandler: 
java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {192.168.0.52}:9042
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:162)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraRDDPartitioner$.getTokenFactory(CassandraRDDPartitioner.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
    at com.system.tableManager.TableCommon.getTableDataframe(TableCommon.scala:56)
    at com.system.user.UserManagement.<init>(UserManagement.scala:51)
    at com.analytics.UI.views.userUI.Login.<init>(Login.java:58)
    at com.analytics.UI.AnalyticsUI.init(AnalyticsUI.java:177)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:682)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.0.52:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.0.52] Connection has been closed))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:231)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1382)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:393)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:155)
    ... 43 more
16/06/21 12:53:13 ERROR AnalyticsUI$Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.analytics.UI.AnalyticsUI$Servlet] in context with path [/Sa_UI] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {192.168.0.52}:9042] with root cause
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.0.52:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.0.52] Connection has been closed))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:231)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1382)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:393)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:155)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraRDDPartitioner$.getTokenFactory(CassandraRDDPartitioner.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
    at com.system.tableManager.TableCommon.getTableDataframe(TableCommon.scala:56)
    at com.system.user.UserManagement.<init>(UserManagement.scala:51)
    at com.analytics.UI.views.userUI.Login.<init>(Login.java:58)
    at com.analytics.UI.AnalyticsUI.init(AnalyticsUI.java:177)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:682)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an entry for cassandra node(ip address and hostname) in /etc/hosts of the machine on which you are running spark.
Also Spark 1.5.2 binary comes with scala 2.10 but the spark-cassandra connector you are using is built on scala 2.11.

Comment: But still, individual class i can run successfully using main method with same Spark Cassandra connector  and get expected output with scala 2.11 and spark 1.5.2

Comment: Thats fine for rdd but in case of streaming and dataframes it would throw an  exception.

Comment: Or it could be because of some dependencies which were not included at the time of building jar

Comment: also tried dataframe for single class working but not while running project